# Autofac SingleInstance not working

Tags: singleton, autofac

I am trying to get a Singleton instance working with Autofac. I'm kind of doing a quasi-mvvm type thing with Winforms, just an experiment so don't get to hung up on that.  But I am trying you have my model be a single instance with a reference in a command (ICommand here is not the WPF variety):

I have the following setup of a container:

```
var cb = new ContainerBuilder();
cb.RegisterType<CalculateCommissionCommand>().As<ICommand<TradeEntry>>().SingleInstance();
cb.RegisterType<CalculationsModel>().As<ICalculationsModel>().SingleInstance();
cb.Register(c => new CalculationsView() { Model = c.Resolve<ICalculationsModel>() }).SingleInstance();
cb.Build();
```

Now the Command takes an ICalculationsModel as a constructor parameter.  However, when I set a value in the Model being passed to the Command, that value does not appear within the model that has already been set withing the CalculationsView.  It seems that the command and the view are being passed different instances of the CalculationsModel despite the "singleInstance" method being called.  Am I missing something?  Why is this happening?

Comment: When I do a bit of digging and put in a static counter with a local auto incrementing instantiated field, I see that in fact autofac is creating new instances each time.  The instance getting passed to the view has ID=1 and the instance passed to the command is ID=2.  That can only happen if the constructor was called twice.  What gives?  Autofac can't be that broken can it?

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the constructor, and see if it is really happening twice

Comment: Yes. The constructor is called twice.

Comment: It's not clear from your code how you are storing/using the container, is it possible you have created multiple containers?  It is definitely not autofac that is wrong.

Comment: It is being instantiated as follows:
ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => new AutofacServiceLocator(ConfigureContainer()));

The code above in my original post is contained in the "Configure Container" and I return cb.Build() from it.  I then use ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<...>().  You think it's serviceLocator creating copies of the container?  Hmmm... let's take a look.

Comment: Yep, that's what it was.  It turns out I am doing something wrong with ServiceLocator.  Thanks jlew.  If you want to repost your comment as an answer I would be happy to credit you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not clear from your code how you are storing/using the container.  It is likely you have created multiple containers.

Answer (score 12):

We hit a similar problem today and this seems to be the only post where this question is asked, so I thought I'd share our experience in the hopes it helps someone out. In the end it was something right in front of our eyes and of course they're usually the hardest problems to solve :-).

In our scenario, we were:

1. Registering a specific implementation of a configuration provider
2. Auto-registering certain types within an assembly.

Something along these lines:

```
var cb = new ContainerBuilder();
cb.RegisterType<FileBasedConfigurationProvider>()
    .As<IConfigurationProvider>()
    .SingleInstance();

cb.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(MailProvider).Assembly)
    .Where(t => !t.IsAbstract && t.Name.EndsWith("Provider"))
    .AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

Stupidly, we didn't think about/realise that the `FileBasedConfigurationProvider` was in the same assembly as the `MailProvider`, so the second registration call basically overwrote the first one; hence, `SingleInstance` "wasn't working".

Hope that helps someone else out!

Comment: +1, I made the exact same mistake today. Its so obvious when you think about it, but its really not the easiest thing to see when you're in the thick of it. Thanks for saving me some debugging time :)

Answer (score 2):

In my case the problem was that the parameter to the method generating the second instance was defined as the class instead of the interface 
i.e.

```
SomeMethod(ClassName parameter)
```

instead of

```
SomeMethod(**I**ClassName parameter)
```

Obvious mistake, but took a few minutes to see it.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had two registrations for a class for different interfaces declaring that each was single instance.  I assumed there would be a single instance of the class... no there's a single instance for each registration.

e.g

```
builder.RegisterType<MyClass>().As<IMyFirstInterface>().SingleInstance();  // 1st instance 
builder.RegisterType<MyClass>().As<IMySecondInterface>().SingleInstance(); // 2nd instance
```

The correct way to do this was...

```
builder
    .RegisterType<MyClass>()
    .As<IMyFirstInterface>()
    .As<IMySecondInterface>()
    .SingleInstance();
```